# How to custom 'Type' in Compare Validator in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, validation

How to reset date Type for Compare Validator in ASP.Net
i am using the dd/MM/yyyy format for the Calendar Extender of a textbox, where as Compare Validater looks for MM/dd/YYYY format.
so how to change date format of Compare Validator.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the DateFormat by changing the [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) of the page(or the whole application in the Web.Config). This is possible in the page directive of the aspx-page or in the codebehind.
Have a look at MSDN for further information: [How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx)

For example(MM/dd/YYYY is US-Culture, isnt it?):

```
<%@ Page UICulture="en-us" Culture="en-US" %>
```